# How can I draw a function graph inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to visualize the architecture of a neural network. My current draft is

[image]

Now I would like to replace all "s" by the graph of a standard logistic function in -6, 6:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$$

How can I do that?

Here is an example which is similar to what I'm looking for:

[image]

### Current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows, snakes}

\tikzstyle{input}=[draw,fill=red!50,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{hidden}=[draw,fill=green!50,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{output}=[draw,fill=white,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{bias}=[draw,dashed,fill=gray!50,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{layer}=[fill=gray!70]

\tikzstyle{stateTransition}=[->, thick]
\DeclareMathOperator{\xor}{XOR}
\newcommand{\width}{0.2}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[layer] (-\width,-1.7) rectangle (\width,1.7);
    \fill[layer] (1+-\width,-1.7) rectangle (1+\width,1.7);
    \fill[layer] (2+-\width,-1.7) rectangle (2+\width,1.7);
    \fill[layer] (3+-\width,-1.7) rectangle (3+\width,1.7);
    \node (l1label) at  (0, -1.9) {3};
    \node (l2label) at  (1, -1.9) {64};
    \node (l3label) at  (2, -1.9) {64};
    \node (l4label) at  (3, -1.9) {1};
    \node (r)[input,fill=red]   at (0, 1) {$s$};
    \node (g)[input,fill=green] at (0, 0) {$s$};
    \node (b)[input,fill=blue]  at (0,-1) {$s$};

    \node (h11)[hidden] at (1, 1.5) {$s$};
    \node (h12)[hidden] at (1, 0.5) {$s$};
    \node[circle, inner sep=0] (h13) at (1,-0.5) {\vdots};
    \node (h14)[hidden] at (1,-1.5) {$s$};
    \node (h21)[hidden] at (2, 1.5) {$s$};
    \node (h22)[hidden] at (2, 0.5) {$s$};
    \node[circle, inner sep=0] (h23) at (2,-0.5) {\vdots};
    \node (h24)[hidden] at (2,-1.5) {$s$};

    \node (o1)[output] at (3,0) {$s$};

    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h12) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h13) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h14) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h12) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h13) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h14) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h12) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h13) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};

    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h24) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h24) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h24) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};

    \draw[stateTransition] (h21) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h22) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.10cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h23) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h24) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};

    \draw [
    thick,
    decoration={
        brace,
        mirror,
        raise=0.5cm
    },
    decorate
] (1+-\width, -1.8) -- (2+\width, -1.8)
node [pos=0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-0.55cm] {50\% dropout};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Side question: Why is `\vdots` not centered / how do I center it?

Comment: Use circle on vdots nodes and set inner sep to 0.

Comment: @percusse `\node[circle, inner sep=0] (h13) at (1,-0.5) {\vdots};` seems not to change anything.

Comment: It at least puts some symmetry no ? Now it is a rectangle and becomes an optical illusion if that's the right word to say. Put `draw` to see what  I mean. It is actually centered.

Comment: @percusse The bottom dot is touching the bottom of the circle, while the top dot is far away from the top of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the distribution, you can use the `path picture` key but keep in mind that the function is drawn over and over again for each node. You might want to draw it once and save it into a `box` to save some time should this get too much.

For the vdots, you can raise it a bit but I would really recommend you not using this notation because it doesn't give the same effect of saying there undefined-many more nodes here. It just puts another node in the path with a strange label.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows, snakes}
\tikzset{dist/.style={path picture= {
    \begin{scope}[x=1pt,y=10pt]
      \draw plot[domain=-6:6] (\x,{1/(1 + exp(-\x))-0.5});
    \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
\tikzstyle{input}=[draw,fill=red!50,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{hidden}=[draw,fill=green!50,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt,dist]
\tikzstyle{output}=[draw,fill=white,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{bias}=[draw,dashed,fill=gray!50,circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{layer}=[fill=gray!70]

\tikzstyle{stateTransition}=[->, thick]

\newcommand{\width}{0.2}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[layer] (-\width,-1.7) rectangle (\width,1.7);
    \fill[layer] (1+-\width,-1.7) rectangle (1+\width,1.7);
    \fill[layer] (2+-\width,-1.7) rectangle (2+\width,1.7);
    \fill[layer] (3+-\width,-1.7) rectangle (3+\width,1.7);
    \node (l1label) at  (0, -1.9) {3};
    \node (l2label) at  (1, -1.9) {64};
    \node (l3label) at  (2, -1.9) {64};
    \node (l4label) at  (3, -1.9) {1};
    \node (r)[input,fill=red]   at (0, 1) {$s$};
    \node (g)[input,fill=green] at (0, 0) {$s$};
    \node (b)[input,fill=blue]  at (0,-1) {$s$};

    \node (h11)[hidden] at (1, 1.5) {};
    \node (h12)[hidden] at (1, 0.5) {};
    \node[circle,inner sep=0] (h13) at (1,-0.5) {\raisebox{5pt}{$\vdots$}};
    \node (h14)[hidden] at (1,-1.5) {};
    \node (h21)[hidden] at (2, 1.5) {};
    \node (h22)[hidden] at (2, 0.5) {};
    \node (h23) at (2,-0.5) {\vdots};
    \node (h24)[hidden] at (2,-1.5) {};

    \node (o1)[output] at (3,0) {$s$};

    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h12) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h13) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (r) -- (h14) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h12) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h13) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (g) -- (h14) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h12) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h13) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (b) -- (h11) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};

    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h11) -- (h24) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h12) -- (h24) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h13) -- (h24) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h22) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h23) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h14) -- (h21) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};

    \draw[stateTransition] (h21) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h22) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.10cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h23) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};
    \draw[stateTransition] (h24) -- (o1) node [midway,above=-0.06cm] {};

    \draw [
    thick,
    decoration={
        brace,
        mirror,
        raise=0.5cm
    },
    decorate
] (1+-\width, -1.8) -- (2+\width, -1.8)
node [pos=0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-0.55cm] {50\% dropout};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]